# Should it be "not allowed to use" or "not allowed to be used"?

Tags: grammar

"The mobile phones are not allowed to use." or "The mobile phones are not allowed to be used."
Which one is correct, and what's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The mobile phones are not allowed to use" is wrong, because it places the phones as the subject, stating that the phones themselves are not allowed to do something. An object would then be expected after "to use" and would state exactly what the phones aren't allowed to do.

"Mobile phones are not allowed to be used" is grammatically correct, but awkward, even after dropping "the" which suggests a specific group of mobile phones are banned. Instead, you can say:

> - Mobile phones are not allowed.
> - Mobile phones may not be used.
> - Please refrain from using mobile phones.

Comment: That helps a lot. Thank you!